# Should I use one [UIImage imageNamed:x] for an icon shown on many views?

Tags: ios

This is mostly a memory concern. Does iOS cache image data loaded from assets separately from the UIImage instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, UIImages loaded via +imageNamed are cached by the system, so you can call it many times, so best use that if you've got the image used in multiple places.  Images created via any of the 'WithContentsOfFile' type methods are not cached.  You can always maintain your own image cache if you want more control.

Via the [UIImage class reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:)

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method locates and loads the image data from disk or asset catelog, and then returns the resulting object.